# Getting list from JSON output into a data frame

Tags: r, json, dataframe, list

I have tried a number of methods that are suggested for similar sounding problems but I can't get them to work....

I am trying to get output from a JSON call into a data frame, but I can't find a way to manipulate the list - it looks as though it should be easy, but all the solutions proposed seem very complicated and I can't get them to work.

An example of the call is:

```
res = GET("https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles?Year=2011&Make=Acura&Model=&units=US&format=json")
data = fromJSON(rawToChar(res$content), flatten = TRUE)
R<-data$Results
S<-R$Specs
```

This then gives me a list of 9 data frames, each with a Name column and a Value column

The Name column is repeated exactly in each data frame

I simply want to get these into a single data frame with the Name column providing column names and the Value columns from each data frame as individual rows.

Any suggestions gratefully received - many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another approach using `rrapply()` (in package `rrapply`) to unnest the nested list to a long data.frame and then using `unstack()` to transform from a long to a wide data.frame:

```
jsonlite::read_json("https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles?Year=2011&Make=Acura&Model=&units=US&format=json")$Results |>
  rrapply::rrapply(how = "bind") |>
  unstack(form = Value ~ Name)

#>         A       B       C        CW       D       E       F       G  Make                                  Model MYR      OH       OL      OW     TWF     TWR       WB    WD
#> 1 37.0079 17.7165 14.1732  2866.006 29.9213 43.3071 36.2205 36.6142 ACURA        CSX 4DR SEDAN FWD /TECH PACKAGE   6 56.6929 178.7402 68.8976 59.0551 59.4488 106.2992 61/39
#> 2  46.063 72.0472 16.5354 4550.3357 33.4646 49.6063 39.3701 43.3071 ACURA            MDX 4DR SUV AWD /TECH/ELITE  10 68.1102 190.9449 78.3465 67.7165 67.7165 108.2677 56/44
#> 3 49.2126 59.8425 14.9606 3946.2698 33.0709 48.8189 38.5827 38.9764 ACURA          RDX 4DR SUV AWD /TECH PACKAGE  10 65.3543 181.8898  73.622 62.2047 62.5984 104.3307 57/43
#> 4 49.2126 28.7402 14.5669 4109.4117 31.4961 45.6693 40.9449 43.7008 ACURA                RL 4DR SEDAN AWD /ELITE   9 57.4803 195.6693 72.8346  61.811  61.811 110.2362 58/42
#> 5 52.7559 24.4094 13.3858 3708.1708 31.8898  46.063 41.3386 45.2756 ACURA           TL 4 DR SEDAN FWD/TECHNOLOGY   9 57.0866 195.6693 74.0157 62.9921 63.3858 109.4488 61/39
#> 6 52.7559 24.4094 13.3858 3970.5206 31.8898  46.063 41.3386 45.2756 ACURA TL 4 DR SEDAN SH-AWD/SH-AWD TECHNOLOGY   9 57.0866 195.6693 74.0157 62.9921 63.3858 109.4488 59/41
#> 7 47.6378 17.3228 13.7795 3406.1379 31.1024 45.2756  38.189 40.9449 ACURA TSX 4DR SEDAN FWD TECH PACKAGE/PREMIUM   9 56.6929 186.2205 72.4409 62.2047 62.2047 106.6929 60/40
#> 8 47.6378 17.3228 13.7795 3686.1246 31.1024 45.2756  38.189 40.9449 ACURA                   TSX 4DR SEDAN FWD V6   9 56.6929 186.2205 72.4409 62.2047 62.2047 106.6929 60/40
#> 9 52.3622 42.9134 12.9921 4550.3357 34.6457 47.2441 42.9134 40.9449 ACURA           ZDX 4DR SUV AWD / TECH ELITE  10 62.9921  192.126 78.3465 67.7165 67.3228 108.2677 58/42
```

Comment: Thanks very much!  That has sorted it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to extract each `Name` and `Value` pair and then bind them together. For one row you can do this:

```r
library(jsonlite)
res <- read_json("https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles?Year=2011&Make=Acura&Model=&units=US&format=json")

do.call(cbind, lapply(
    res$Results[[1]]$Specs,
    \(x) setNames(data.frame(x$Value), x$Name)
))

#    Make                           Model MYR       OL      OW      OH       WB       CW       A       B       C       D       E       F       G     TWF     TWR    WD
# 1 ACURA CSX 4DR SEDAN FWD /TECH PACKAGE   6 178.7402 68.8976 56.6929 106.2992 2866.006 37.0079 17.7165 14.1732 29.9213 43.3071 36.2205 36.6142 59.0551 59.4488 61/39
```

Or to apply this to your entire result.

```r
do.call(
    rbind,
    lapply(res$Results, \(dat) do.call(cbind, lapply(dat$Specs, \(x) setNames(data.frame(x$Value), x$Name))))
)
#    Make                                  Model MYR       OL      OW      OH       WB        CW       A       B       C       D       E       F       G     TWF     TWR
# 1 ACURA        CSX 4DR SEDAN FWD /TECH PACKAGE   6 178.7402 68.8976 56.6929 106.2992  2866.006 37.0079 17.7165 14.1732 29.9213 43.3071 36.2205 36.6142 59.0551 59.4488
# 2 ACURA            MDX 4DR SUV AWD /TECH/ELITE  10 190.9449 78.3465 68.1102 108.2677 4550.3357  46.063 72.0472 16.5354 33.4646 49.6063 39.3701 43.3071 67.7165 67.7165
# 3 ACURA          RDX 4DR SUV AWD /TECH PACKAGE  10 181.8898  73.622 65.3543 104.3307 3946.2698 49.2126 59.8425 14.9606 33.0709 48.8189 38.5827 38.9764 62.2047 62.5984
# 4 ACURA                RL 4DR SEDAN AWD /ELITE   9 195.6693 72.8346 57.4803 110.2362 4109.4117 49.2126 28.7402 14.5669 31.4961 45.6693 40.9449 43.7008  61.811  61.811
# 5 ACURA           TL 4 DR SEDAN FWD/TECHNOLOGY   9 195.6693 74.0157 57.0866 109.4488 3708.1708 52.7559 24.4094 13.3858 31.8898  46.063 41.3386 45.2756 62.9921 63.3858
# 6 ACURA TL 4 DR SEDAN SH-AWD/SH-AWD TECHNOLOGY   9 195.6693 74.0157 57.0866 109.4488 3970.5206 52.7559 24.4094 13.3858 31.8898  46.063 41.3386 45.2756 62.9921 63.3858
# 7 ACURA TSX 4DR SEDAN FWD TECH PACKAGE/PREMIUM   9 186.2205 72.4409 56.6929 106.6929 3406.1379 47.6378 17.3228 13.7795 31.1024 45.2756  38.189 40.9449 62.2047 62.2047
# 8 ACURA                   TSX 4DR SEDAN FWD V6   9 186.2205 72.4409 56.6929 106.6929 3686.1246 47.6378 17.3228 13.7795 31.1024 45.2756  38.189 40.9449 62.2047 62.2047
# 9 ACURA           ZDX 4DR SUV AWD / TECH ELITE  10  192.126 78.3465 62.9921 108.2677 4550.3357 52.3622 42.9134 12.9921 34.6457 47.2441 42.9134 40.9449 67.7165 67.3228
```

##### Alternative to `jsonlite::read_json()`

I do not know why `read_json()` would give you an error as it seems to work when I use it. However, you can also get the `res` object by doing:

```r
response <- httr::GET("https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles?Year=2011&Make=Acura&Model=&units=US&format=json")
res  <- jsonlite::fromJSON(httr::content(response), simplifyVector = FALSE)
```

Then the rest of the code is the same.

Comment: Thanks - when I try that I get "Error in read_json("https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles?Year=2011&Make=Acura&Model=&units=US&format=json") : 
  Unrecognized json format: gov/api/vehicles?Year=2011&Make=Acura&Model=&units=US&format=json"

From the read_json command

Comment: @DJD I don't know why that is as it works for me but you can also get it using `httr::GET()` - see my update.